Proving $(S \circ R)^{-1} = R^{-1} \circ S^{-1}$
I need to prove the following statement from Velleman's How to Prove It (p. 176):

Suppose $R$ is a relation from $A$ to $B$ and $S$ is a relation from $B$ to $C$. Prove that $(S \circ R)^{-1} = R^{-1} \circ S^{-1}$.

My proof
$(c, a) \in (S \circ R)^{-1}$ iff $(a, c) \in (S \circ R)$ iff $\exists b \in B : (a, b) \in R \space \text{and} \space (b, c) \in S$ iff $\exists b \in B : (b, a) \in R^{-1} \space \text{and} \space (c, b) \in S^{-1}$ iff $\exists b \in B : (c, b) \in S^{-1} \space \text{and} \space (b, a) \in R^{-1}$ iff $(c, a) \in R^{-1} \circ S^{-1}. \square$
Can you please confirm that this is valid? I feel the suspicion that I might have spelled out more carefully some steps which are implicit in my current version of the proof.
Edit
Note that this question has been answered here. The proof is identical to mine.

If you want to ask mainly about correctness of your approach, you should probably use the tag ([tag:solution-verification]) See the tag info for more details about this tag.

You can also have a look at the answer given here: How to show $(S \circ R)^{-1} = R^{-1} \circ S^{-1}$?

Indeed, the proof there is the same as yours (and it is ok). However, for posts looking for feedback or verification of a proposed solution. "Is this proof correct?" is too broad . Please follow the link given in Martin's first comment.
